# General Question: Balance Among Three People

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

Just thinking about this scenario. If three friends go out for a trip, A spent $45, B $35, and C $10, is there a general formula to figure out that C needs to transfer $15 to C and $5 to B to make it balance?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you mean that A transfers $15, not $10, subtract the average of the three values from any value greater than the average to get the amount they need to donate.

Comment: I don't follow the logic. If A spent more than C, why would A transfer money to C? If you're aiming to have all three spending the same, then surely C should be transferring money to A and B?

Comment: Sorry guys what i meant to say is C should transfer $15 to A and $5 to B

Comment: Just 1. Place the names on column A (Peter, Simon, William), 2. Place the expenses on column B (45U$, 35U$, 10U$), 3. Calculate the average on cell B4 (`=AVERAGE(B1:B3)`), 4. On cell C1 place the formula `=$B$4-A1`, 5. Copy this cell (or drag) to cells C2 & C3. 6. Your result will be that Peter should recover 15U$, Simon 5U$ and William should pay 20U$.Is that ok for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar question on the math part of stackexchange. It appears to be an NP-problem. So there is no smart way to solve the problem in generel. You can write code that can do it for three persons, but there are no generel formula as you ask for.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63874/is-there-a-simple-math-behind-splitting-multiple-bills-evenly-across-many-people/63879